# Cambiar Fondo de html

Tags: html, fondo

No soy experto en programación por el cual les consulto lo siguiente.
He desarrollado una pagina HTML, la cual cargo en un webserver de un PLC, para tomar datos y mostrar en la página. 
Por medio de la expresion  :="webdata".VARIABLE:  tomo los datos que necesito. 
Al principio actualizaba la pagina con   , si bien parpadeaba,  me permitía mediante una función que cargaba en el BODY actualizar el fondo de la página de rojo a negro en función del estado de una variable.
Para evitar que parpadee, empece a utilizar un "div" para actualizar los datos a la página sin que parpadee la pantalla. 
Pero ahora no puedo cambiar el color de fondo sin actualizar toda la página, pero esto me genere que parpadee de nuevo la pantalla.

Adjunto código. Ya he probado moviendo el body dentro y fuera de los div que me actualizan los valores pero no logré resultados

```
<head>
    <title>PANTALLA</title>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
         function() {
         setInterval(function() {
            $('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #time');
        }, 1000);  //Delay 1 segundo
        });
    </script>


    <script>
        function cambiarColor(){
            var valor=:="webdata".COLOR:;   //ACÁ TOMO EL DATO PARA CAMBIAR EL COLOR

            if (valor == '1') {
                document.body.style.background ='red';  //colorCambiado
            } else {
                document.body.style.background ='black';    //colorNormal
            }}
    </script>
</head>


<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}

    .tg .tg-C1FX{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:140px;color:#32cb00;}
.tg .tg-C2FX{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:100px;color:#ffffff;}
.tg .tg-C3FX{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:140px;color:#32cb00;}
.tg .tg-C4FX{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:100px;color:#32cb00;}

.tg .tg-C1FY{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:210px;color:#ffffff;}
.tg .tg-C2FY{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:110px;color:#ffffff;}
.tg .tg-C3FY{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:210px;color:#ffffff;}
.tg .tg-C4FY{font-family:FreeSans;font-weight:bold;font-size:110px;color:#ffffff;}

</style>


<div id="refresh">
    <div id="time">

        <body onload="cambiarColor()">

            <table  width="100%" class="tg">

                <tr>
                    <td class="tg-C1FX" colspan="2">VELOCIDAD</td>
                        <td align="right" class="tg-C3FX" colspan="2">GRAMAJE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="tg-C1FY">:="webdata".VEL:</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tg-C2FY">m/min</td>
                        <td align="right" class="tg-C3FY">:="webdata".GRAMAJE:</td>
                        <td align="right" class="tg-C4FY">g/m2</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </body>
    </div>
</div>
```